# How to properly Init a custom UITableviewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, initialization

I am using the following 2 methods to return a custom cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *key = [self keyForIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if ([key isEqualToString:DoneButtonCellKey]) {
        cell = [self [self doneButtonCellForIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    } else {
        //code to return default cell...
    }
}
```

Then:

```
- (DoneButtonCell *)doneButtonCellForIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DoneButtonCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DoneButtonCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;

}
```

What is the correct init method to use with the cell here so I can change some properties of the cell when it is initialized?

EDIT: I found the problem, as the init/awakeFromNib methods were not being called for me. I tracked down the error and it was that I had not changed the "Custom Class" from UITableViewCell to my custom class. Now awakeFromNib AND initWithCoder work as described below.

Comment: The cell is already init'd inside the `dequeueReusablCellWithIdentiier:` Method, you can change all it's parameters before you return it !, what params do you want to tweak ?

Comment: I was hoping that I could set up a number of things including text label.numberOfLines, or backgroundColor etc. But this is all stuff I don't want to have to do every time I instantiate a cell.

Comment: I understand you, then you must do it in the `DoneButtonCell` class,  in the awakeFromNib method, I'll post an answer to show you how

Comment: Which init method is called depends on how you create your cells. Are you creating them entirely in code, in a xib, or in a storyboard?

Comment: I am using xib files. initiWithCoder, awakeFromNib, and initWithStyle are all not being called

Comment: For me, I had a base cell class and the derived classes weren't calling [super awakeFromNib].  The 'EDIT' you provided in the original question somehow led me to the solution for my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do your changes inside the `DoneButtonCell`'s class, either in the

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
 .. essential to call super ..
 super.awakeFromNib()
 //Changes done directly here, we have an object
}
```

Or the `initWithCoder:` method:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder
{
   self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

   if(self)
   {
     //Changes here after init'ing self
   }

   return self;
}
```

Comment: Neither of these are getting called in my case

Comment: I found the problem I was having, and added it to my question above. This was indeed exactly what I was looking for thanks!

Comment: Sorry just saw your issue, I would've told you first thing to check the custom class :) glad it worked for you, happy hacking !

Comment: this answer that's not cover the main issue of the question, why this answer was accepted?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Swift, remember the easy way to ensure a view is initialized when it is created is to use the didSet method.  For example, to make a UIImageView into a round shape you could add code like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView! {
    didSet {
        // Make the profile icon circle.
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Comment: nice one, what if the profileImageView is there in the UITableViewCell and when the cell come on screen after going off screen will it be called again?

Comment: No.  The cell is created once and then reused in multiple places.  Check out the prepare for reuse method if you need to reset something each time the cell is used.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I am initialising custom cells

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"FileTableViewCell";

    FileTableViewCell *cell = (FileTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FileTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    // Configure the cell here...
      // Configure the cell.
FileRepresentation* fileRepresentation = _fileList[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [self userFilename:[fileRepresentation.fileName stringByDeletingPathExtension]];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [fileRepresentation modifiedDate];


cell.accessoryView=nil;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
[cell.progressIndicator setHidden:YES];

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_fileImageName];

// Disable any user interaction while processing a request
if (_fileIsOpen || _creatingDocument || _deletingDocument) {

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

} else {

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;

}

}
```

Comment: then programmatic customization can happen in - (void)awakeFromNib ?

Comment: So did I, the dequeReusableCell method now returns a cell if one is not created

Comment: This answer helps me: 
`NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FileTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];`
</br>
`cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];`

Answer (score 1):

1. First try to dequeue a cell if possible using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method of UITableView.
2. If cell is not available (`nil`) use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"<#your custom cell nib name#>" owner:nil options:nil][0]` to initialize it.
3. In your custom cell's .m file, implement `initWithCoder:` initializer for custom initialization code:

---

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {  
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];  
    //your custom initialization code  
    return self;  
}
```

---

This is the designated initializer that is called when any view is loaded from a nib with `loadNibNamed`, like a custom table view cell.

Comment: Cell should not be nil. If it is, use `tableView.registerNib(<#nib: UINib#>, forCellReuseIdentifier: <#String#>)` You shouldn't be manually instantiating a nib in `cellForRowAtIndex`…

Comment: @JohnGibb yes, I agree with you, one don't need to worry about getting a `nil` value while dequeueing if he has already registered a nib/class for cell. However, I didn't really get how manually instantiating a nib could be harmful. Could you please explain?

Comment: It won't be re-used that way, will it? Why NOT use `registerNib` instead?

Comment: @JohnGibb Oh! that depends how efficiently you can manage that? Apple uses the same method internally to unarchive a nib when a nib is designated for table view cell  by `registerNib` method.

Comment: Ok, sure, you could write your own efficient cell pool for reuse. However I don't think that's the best advice for most developers coming to this page :)

Comment: @JohnGibb No offense taken! I can understand what you are really thinking about ;)

Comment: Outlets won't be initialised in initWithCoder yet. Use awakeFromNib to avoid that.

Comment: @marsbear you are right. `awakeFromNib` is always a better place. I was only talking about the designated initializer.